# How to reliably append text to the end of a text box using wxPython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

Edit2: Solved! I have no idea what changed or why, but now even a RichTextCtrl appends reliably. I left the old message below, despite this.

So I'm writing a GUI in python using wxPython. One of the main elements of this GUI is a textbox.

Features I need:

1. The ability to reliably append text to the end of the textbox.
2. Prevent user editing the textbox
3. Vertical Scroll bar
   Features I'd like:
4. User can select text even when more lines are being appended
5. Text color can be changed

With that in mind I tried to do use the [RichTextCtrl](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl-class.html) provided by wxPython. 
However there appears no way to reliably add text to the end of the text box. The AppendText method is not reliable. If I click a location in the textbox while several lines are being appended this way it is likely one or more of the lines will be inserted where-ever I moved the cursor.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reliably append text to a RichTextCtrl? I might be able to clear it and replace all of its text with new text every time I want to append something, but I fear the performance hit from this would be severe. If there is a different text control that would be more appropriate for this please suggest it.

Edit: Using a regular TextCtrl appends reliably. Still no luck with a RichTextCtrl.

Comment: why dont you use an htmlWindow?

Answer (score 0):

AppendText works for me on Windows with wxPython 2.9. If you want to prevent the user from editing, you'll need to use the wx.TE_READ_ONLY style flag. To make a vertical scroll bar appear, add the wx.TE_MULTILINE flag too.

The wxPython demo shows how to change text color. Basically you programmatically select a range and set a style / font for that selection. Getting the ability to select text while appending may not be possible. You would probably have to set up some kind of buffer for the appends and append after the user finishes selecting or keep track of what the user is selecting, append and then reselect.